# Alert not showing after loading entire content of all iframes on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
          <iframe width="400px" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
          <iframe width="400px" src="http://www.phpacademy.org"></iframe>
          <iframe width="400px" src="http://www.jquery.com"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

below is code in custom.js

```
$(window).(on.('load', function () {
    alert('All content loaded.');
}));
```

I want the alert to display when all the three iframes are loaded on the page.

Comment: What kind of jQuery usage is this? `(on.('`???

Comment: Syntax errors. Do: `$(window).on('load', function() {...})`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Comment: your code has a syntax error 

to subscripe to  `load` event

`$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});`

Comment: @Rk have you got your solution , i think answer posted by users is not working

Comment: yes i got it , it is `$(window).on.('load', function () {
    alert('All content loaded.');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you used for load is wrong, you should use

```
$(window).on.('load', function () {
    alert('All content loaded.');
});
```

Comment: It is generally discouraged to use event handlers like this. The preferred method is using `$(element).on('event', function() { do_something(); } )`. Besides, this does not address the problem OP has. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click#11878976

Answer (score 1):

Write this way

```
   $(window).load(function() {
    alert("All content loaded.");
  });
```

Comment: It is generally discouraged to use event handlers like this. The preferred method is using `$(element).on('event', function() { do_something(); } )`. Besides, this does not address the problem OP has. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click#11878976